# App not in IPhone Notification Center option in Settings

Tags: iphone, ios7

I am developing an app which enabled push notification.When receiving notification badge value is set on app icon but notification not displaying on top of the screen.App not in IPhone Notification Center option in Settings.any help will be appreciated.thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the app open when you are receiving the notification?

Comment: yes it is working fine

Comment: did it solve your problem?

Comment: I meant i can open the app when notification receiving

Comment: Did you ask for all these permission in appdelegate: [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
  (UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert)];

Comment: http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/